# Exception when receiving data from Back end to Front end

Tags: python, json, flutter, dart, flask

I've created a simple flutter app which will get data from an api in json format sent from the backend (Python flask) and print out the data on click of a button.

When I click on the button, I get the error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)]
> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 36820

I'm very new to flutter, please tell me where I did wrong and help me figure it out.

Flutter Dart code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new HomePage(),
));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

List data;

Future<String> getData() async {
var response = await http.get(
  Uri.encodeFull("http://127.0.0.1:5000/ "),
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
);
data = json.decode(response.body);
print(data);

return "Success!";
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
   body: new Center(
     child: new RaisedButton(
       child: new Text("Get data"),
       onPressed: getData,
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return jsonify({"about": "Hello World!"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: I believe the problem can be in this line `Uri.encodeFull("http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ")`. The address you are pointing to can be wrong if you are running Emulator. If it is an Android Emulator - try to change the IP address to `10.0.2.2`. Additionally, you can try to run `ifconfig` and try received IP address from there, e.g. `192.168.0.109`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running your back-end from `localhost`. In this case, `127.0.0.1` will only work if you run the application on your PC (and not another phone/device. Not sure about simulators though).

Trying to access `127.0.0.1` from a phone is like trying to access a server hosted on your phone (which evidently will not be found).

So, to run the app on your phone, you need to find your PC's (private) IP address, using e.g. `ifconfig` from your terminal. Once you get this IP address, use the URL `{your-priv-IP}:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1:5000` in your code. Make sure though that your PC and phone are connected to the same Wifi network for this to work.

Comment: I tried what you said,But it didnt do anything... Im running my app on my android studio emulator .Should I just replace the address in m flutter code with my ipv4 address?

Comment: A comment by rceman suggests using 10.0.2.2 in case of an android simulator, I guess you can give it a try. So, something like `http://10.0.2.2:5000`